# Unable to empty the state after submit (React js)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mern, react-state

This is my Component,

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Box, styled } from '@mui/system'
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close'
import {
    Button,
    Grid,
    Select,
    FormControl,
    InputLabel,
    Icon,
    IconButton,
    Typography,
    TextField,
    Dialog,
    MenuItem,
    DialogTitle as MuiDialogTitle,
    DialogContent as MuiDialogContent,
    DialogActions as MuiDialogActions
} from '@mui/material';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { setDate } from 'date-fns/esm';
import { weekdays } from 'moment';
import { CompressOutlined } from '@mui/icons-material';

const label = { inputProps: { 'aria-label': 'Checkbox demo' } };
const DialogTitleRoot = styled(MuiDialogTitle)(({ theme }) => ({
    margin: 0,
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    '& .closeButton': {
        position: 'absolute',
        right: theme.spacing(1),
        top: theme.spacing(1),
        color: theme.palette.grey[500],
    },
}))

const DialogTitle = ((props) => {
    const { children, onClose } = props
    return (
        <DialogTitleRoot disableTypography>
            <Typography variant="h6">{children}</Typography>
            {onClose ? (
                <IconButton
                    style={{ marginLeft: '15px' }}
                    aria-label="Close"
                    className='closeButton'
                    onClick={onClose}
                >
                    <CloseIcon />
                </IconButton>
            ) : null}
        </DialogTitleRoot>
    )
})

const DialogContent = styled(MuiDialogContent)(({ theme }) => ({
    "&.root": {
        padding: theme.spacing(2),
    },
}))

const DialogActions = styled(MuiDialogActions)(({ theme }) => ({
    '&.root': {
        margin: 0,
        padding: theme.spacing(1),
    },
}))

export default function CustomDialogBox({
    open,
    close,
    setDays,
    data,
    editDays,
}) {

    const [weekdays, setWeekdays] = useState([{
        day: 'S',
        fullName: 'Sunday',
        select: false
    },
    {
        day: 'M',
        fullName: 'Monday',
        select: false
    },
    {
        day: 'T',
        fullName: 'Tuesday',
        select: false
    },
    {
        day: 'W',
        fullName: 'Wednesday',
        select: false
    },
    {
        day: 'T',
        fullName: 'Thursday',
        select: false
    },
    {
        day: 'F',
        fullName: 'Friday',
        select: false
    },
    {
        day: 'S',
        fullName: 'Saturday',
        select: false
    }])

    useEffect(() => {
        {
            if (data?.length > 0) {
                setWeekdays((prevWeekdays) => {
                    const newWeekdays = prevWeekdays.map((weekday) => {
                        if (data.includes(weekday.fullName)) {
                            return {
                                ...weekday,
                                select: true,
                            };
                        }
                        return weekday;
                    });
                    return newWeekdays;
                });
            }
        }
    }, [data]);
    useEffect(() => {
        {
            if (editDays?.length > 0) {
                setWeekdays((prevWeekdays) => {
                    const newWeekdays = prevWeekdays.map((weekday) => {
                        if (editDays.includes(weekday.fullName)) {
                            return {
                                ...weekday,
                                select: true,
                            };
                        }
                        return weekday;
                    });
                    return newWeekdays;
                });
            }
        }
    }, [editDays]);



    const onSubmit = async () => {
        let valid = weekdays.every(item => item.select === false)
        if (!valid) {
            const weekdayfltr = weekdays.filter((item) => (item.select ? item !== '' : ''))
            setDays(weekdayfltr.map(item => item.fullName))
            close()
            let clearSelected = weekdays.map((item) => { return { ...item, select: false } })
            setWeekdays(clearSelected)
        }
        else {
            toast.error('Select atleast one day !', {
                position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_LEFT
            })
            setDays(...weekdays)
        }
    };

    const handleClick = (obj1, i1) => {
        const newArr = weekdays.map((obj, i) => {
            if (i === i1) {
                return { ...obj, select: !obj.select };
            }
            return obj;
        });

        setWeekdays(newArr);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Dialog
                onClose={close}
                aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title"
                open={open}
            >
                <DialogTitle
                    id="customized-dialog-title"
                    onClose={close}
                >
                    Recurrence Days
                </DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent dividers style={{ width: 500, height: 230 }}>
                    <Grid container spacing={12} gutterBottom>


                        <Grid item lg={12} md={12} sm={12} xs={12} sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
                            <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }} style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }} >
                                <FormControl sx={{ mt: -3 }} fullWidth tabIndex={1}>
                                    <div>
                                        <Typography sx={{ fontSize: '18px', mb: 1, }}>Repeat on:</Typography>
                                        <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
                                            {weekdays?.map((obj, i) => (
                                                <Avatar
                                                    sx={{
                                                        bgcolor: `${obj.select ? "#1a73e8" : "grey"}`,
                                                        height: "25px",
                                                        color: "white",
                                                        width: "25px",
                                                        fontSize: "12px"
                                                    }}
                                                    onClick={() => handleClick(obj, i)}
                                                >
                                                    {obj.day}
                                                </Avatar>
                                            ))}

                                        </Stack>
                                    </div>
                                </FormControl>
                            </Box>
                            <Grid item xs={10.5}>

                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <>
                        <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            type="submit"
                            style={{ backgroundColor: "#898db5", color: "white" }}
                            onClick={() => onSubmit()}
                        >
                            Done
                        </Button>
                        <ToastContainer />
                    </>

                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is my state:

```
const [weekdays, setWeekdays] = useState([{
        day: 'S',
        fullName: 'Sunday',
        select: false
    },
    {
        day: 'M',
        fullName: 'Monday',
        select: false
    },
    {
        day: 'T',
        fullName: 'Tuesday',
        select: false
    },
    {
        day: 'W',
        fullName: 'Wednesday',
        select: false
    },
    {
        day: 'T',
        fullName: 'Thursday',
        select: false
    },
    {
        day: 'F',
        fullName: 'Friday',
        select: false
    },
    {
        day: 'S',
        fullName: 'Saturday',
        select: false
    }])
```

I am trying in this way after the submit:

```
const onSubmit = async () => {
        let valid = weekdays.every(item => item.select === false)
        if (!valid) {
            const weekdayfltr = weekdays.filter((item) => (item.select ? item !== '' : ''))
            setDays(weekdayfltr.map(item => item.fullName))
            close()
            let clearSelected = weekdays.map((item) => { return { ...item, select: false } })
            setWeekdays(clearSelected)
        }
        else {
            toast.error('Select atleast one day !', {
                position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_LEFT
            })
            setDays(...weekdays)
        }
    };
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjlmg.png)

My issue is I want to deselect the selected state.But I am unable to do it dont know what is the reason.
Any suggestion.Thanks in Advanced..........

//             Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum,
// numquam ad ullam adipisci accusantium sint eveniet enim nam corrupti officiis? Tenetur nemo
// aspernatur, totam architecto quia omnis, earum mollitia, inventore quisquam tempore ratione beatae
// veritatis error veniam facere dolor quaerat.

Comment: In your onSubmit function, the setDays function seems to expect an array so the last setDays is wrong. Do setDays([...weekdays]) instead.

Comment: not working..........

Comment: Put `clearSelected `  and `setWeekdays` before `close()` and try to change `clearSelected` => `let clearSelected = [...weekdays].map((item) => { return { ...item, select: false } })`